# how to get two word from a input field and make url based on another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

here i have two input field as like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#business_name").keyup(function() {
      var Text = $(this).val();
      Text = Text.toLowerCase();
      Text = Text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g,'-');
      $("#business_url").val(Text);        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="business_name" name="business_name" placeholder="Business Name" />
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="business_url" name="business_url" placeholder="Business URL" />
```

now I want if someone wrote : **My Business Name** on first input field then 2nd field it will be write `mybusiness` thats it but now it showed my-business-name i dont want this (I need only two word if it will take longer name then it only shows first two word thats it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the first two words you can `split()` the string in to an array by spaces and then use `slice()` to get the first two elements of the resulting array. Then you can join it back together before displaying in the `input`.

Also note I added `trim()` and a regex to replace multiple whitespace with a single one, otherwise it would affect how `split()` builds the array and could end up missing words.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#business_name").on('input', e => {
    var text = $(e.target).val().trim().replace(/\s+/, ' ').toLowerCase().split(' ').slice(0, 2).join('');
    $("#business_url").val(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="business_name" name="business_name" placeholder="Business Name" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="business_url" name="business_url" placeholder="Business URL" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After replacing certain characters with ' ' count the number of ' ' in the string. If the count is 2 stop replacing or you can return from the function.

Look at the modified code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var count = 0;
   $("#business_name").keyup(function() {
      var Text = $(this).val();
      Text = Text.toLowerCase();
      Text = Text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g,' ');
      count = (Text.split("-")).length - 1;
      if (count == 2) {
          return;
      }
      $("#business_url").val(Text);        
    });
});
```